# Bootstrap carousel brakes after hover the menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a strange behaviour using a certain menu effect with Bootstrap carousel in the same page.
Basically, if I hover over the menu, Bootstrap carousel brakes, and give me the following error:

Chrome:

```
Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined
```

Firefox:

```
    $next[0] is undefined
```

This is the Js **Updated** code i'm using for the effect:

```
   var marker = $('#marker'),
    current = $('.current');

// Initialize the marker position and the active class
current.addClass('active');
marker.css({
    // Place the marker in the middle of the border
    bottom: -(marker.height() / 2),
    left: current.position().left,
    width: current.outerWidth(),
    display: "block"
});


if (Modernizr.csstransitions) {
  console.log("using css3 transitions");
$('li.list').mouseover(function () {
    var self = $(this),
        offsetLeft = self.position().left,
        // Use the element under the pointer OR the current page item
        width = self.outerWidth() || current.outerWidth(),
        // Ternary operator, because if using OR when offsetLeft is 0, it is considered a falsy value, thus causing a bug for the first element.
        left = offsetLeft == 0 ? 0 : offsetLeft || current.position().left;
  // Play with the active class
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    self.addClass('active');
    marker.css({
        left: left,
        width: width,
    });
});

// When the mouse leaves the menu
$('ul.UlList').mouseleave(function () {
  // remove all active classes, add active class to the current page item
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    current.addClass('active');
  // reset the marker to the current page item position and width
    marker.css({
        left: current.position().left,
        width: current.outerWidth()
    });
});

} else {
console.log("using jquery animate");

$('li.list').mouseover(function () {
    var self = $(this),
        offsetLeft = self.position().left,
        // Use the element under the pointer OR the current page item
        width = self.outerWidth() || current.outerWidth(),
        // Ternary operator, because if using OR when offsetLeft is 0, it is considered a falsy value, thus causing a bug for the first element.
        left = offsetLeft == 0 ? 0 : offsetLeft || current.position().left;
  // Play with the active class
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    self.addClass('active');
    marker.stop().animate({
        left: left,
        width: width,
    }, 300);
});

// When the mouse leaves the menu
$('ul.UlList').mouseleave(function () {
  // remove all active classes, add active class to the current page item
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    current.addClass('active');
  // reset the marker to the current page item position and width
    marker.stop().animate({
        left: current.position().left,
        width: current.outerWidth()
    }, 300);
});
};
```

And here is a codepen that recreates the issue:
http://codepen.io/florinsimion/pen/AXaaOK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because `$('li')` will match all the `li` tags on your page, including the carousel ones. You need to select `li` tags of your menu:

```
$('ul > li').mouseover(....)
 //^ add UL as parent for all your events
```

A ***better*** solution would be using a specific class for your menu:

```
current = $('.my-menu .current');
$('.my-menu li').mouseover(....);
$('ul.my-menu').mouseleave(....);
$('.my-menu .active').removeClass('active');
```

Don't forget your CSS, please take a look at this demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AXaaap

Comment: Thank you for answer...i have updated my pen but the issue remain.

Comment: Please take a look at this demo http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AXaaap You need to do that for all menu selectors + CSS !